# Solving a boundary value problem with boundary condition at infinity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, greens-function

I want to find the Green function for 
$$u'' +2u'-3u=f(x)$$
for which $0<x< \infty, u(0) = 0, \lim_{x\to \infty} u(x)=0$.

However, first I have to solve this bvp and I do not know how to solve it because of the condition that $\lim_{x\to \infty} u(x)=0$.

*To add, in the question it is said that we can take $f(x)=e^{-6x}$. During my research, I saw that to use the boundary condition we should know have that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=c$ for some constant $c$. We can see that the function $f$ satisfies this condition.*

Comment: The function $f$ does not enter into the Green's function, it is replaced by a delta function and then the Green's function is used to solve the BVP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to solve
$$
u''(t)+2u'(t)-3u(t)=\delta(t-s)
$$
or
$$
u''(t)+2u'(t)-3u(t)=0\text{ for }t\ne s
$$
with the conditions $u(0)=0$, $u(s^-)=u(s^+)$, $u'(s^-)+1=u'(s^+)$ and $u(\infty)=0$. On the first part the solution has thus to be $u(t)=A(e^{t}-e^{-3t})$ and on the second segment $u(t)=Be^{-3t}$ The connecting condition is 
$$
A(e^{s}-e^{-3s})=Be^{-3s}\implies B=A(e^{4s}-1)\\~\\
A(e^s+3e^{-3s})+1=-3Be^{-3s}=-3A(e^{s}-e^{-3s})\implies 1=-4Ae^s
$$
so that in combination of all the different solutions the Green function is 
\begin{align}
G(t,s)&=\begin{cases}
-\frac14 e^{-s} (e^{t}-e^{-3t})&t\le s,\\
-\frac14(e^{3s}-e^{-s})e^{-3t}&t>s.
\end{cases}\\
&=-\frac{e^{2s}}4(e^{\min(s,t)}-e^{-3\min(s,t)})\,e^{-3\max(s,t)}\\
&=-\frac{e^{-s}}4(e^{t-4\max(0,t-s)}-e^{-3t})
\end{align}

Comment: Can you please explain how did you write the conditions?

Comment: These are the standard conditions for a second order linear ODE with a Dirac delta on the right side, which you get for the Green function for fixed $s$, $u(t)=G(t,s)$.

Comment: The Dirac-Delta is, among other representations, the second derivative of $\max(0,t)$. An expression in solutions of the homogeneous equation that looks locally like $at+b+\max(0,t-s)$ is $-\frac14e^{t-4\max(0,t-s)}$, which you then have to complement with a homogeneous solution to satisfy the boundary conditions.

Comment: @Ninja The idea is that the delta function is embedded entirely in the $u''$ term, meaning that $u'$ has a jump of $1$ as you go from left to right through $s$, and $u$ remains continuous at $s$.